# Can't display single data fetched by API. React-JS

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to display the required data from an API response but it's not visible. Here's the API fetch code:

```
async function getNFTData(){
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.rarible.org/v0.1/items/${chain}:${address}:${Id}`)
    const data = await response.json()
    setNfts(data.items)
    console.log(data);
  }
```

And it displays data perfectly in console, but when I try to display data in frontend I get no result.
Here's the code to display data:

```
getNFTData?.meta?.name
```

Here's the API response in console.log:

> auctions: []
> blockchain: "POLYGON"
> collection: "POLYGON:0xdf07c9a4e4e0adafeaf769934e933277471f4c36"
> contract: "POLYGON:0xdf07c9a4e4e0adafeaf769934e933277471f4c36"
> creators: [{…}]
> deleted: false
> id: "POLYGON:0xdf07c9a4e4e0adafeaf769934e933277471f4c36:55"
> lastUpdatedAt: "2022-05-15T20:48:12.780Z"
> lazySupply: "0"
> meta: {name: 'Tiny Turtles #55', description: 'Tiny Turtles is a collection of 3270 randomly gene…urated NFTs that exist on the Polygon Blockchain.', tags: Array(0), genres: Array(0), attributes: Array(3), …}
> mintedAt: "2022-05-15T20:48:11Z"
> originOrders: []
> pending: []
> sellers: 0
> supply: "1"
> tokenId: "55"
> totalStock: "0"

Now if I use; **getNFTData.meta.name**, I get an error the **meta not defined** but when I use **getNFTData?.meta?.name** nothing is displayed and there's no error in console.log.

I'm confused what am I doing wrong.

Comment: `getNFTData` to reference a function, `getNFTData()` to call it. I'd also remove the question marks because they just hide the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have set the response in some variable defined on top using setNfts(data.items),,, you should use that variable to print the values. As per the code getNFTData is a funcfion not some variable or constant.

Comment: So I added a var in the function and then used a return(<h1>{}</h1>) to get the output but I'm not seeing anything on frontend but in console.log I see error that meta is undefined. I think the error in rendering the async function. Anyone knows how do I render an async function?